# Marshal an array of object

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I have the following program:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class SwitchTime
{
    public byte st1 { get; set; }
    public byte st2 { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Size=3)]
class SwitchParam
{
    public byte sp1 { get; set; }
    public byte sp2 { get; set; }
    public byte sp3 { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class SwitchRecord
{
    public SwitchTime switchTime;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public SwitchParam[] switchParams;
}
```

And I have:

```
void populate( SwitchRecord SR)
{
    SR.switchTime = new SwitchTime();
    SR.switchTime.st1 = 1;
    SR.switchTime.st2 = 2;
    SR.switchParams = new SwitchParam[2];
    SR.switchParams[0] = new SwitchParam();
    SR.switchParams[0].sp1 = 3;
    SR.switchParams[0].sp2 = 4;
    SR.switchParams[0].sp3 = 5;
    SR.switchParams[1] = new SwitchParam();
    SR.switchParams[1].sp1 = 6;
    SR.switchParams[1].sp2 = 7;
    SR.switchParams[1].sp3 = 8;
}

byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);//Exception here
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SwitchRecord SR = new SwitchRecord();
    populate(SR);
    byte[] b = StructureToByteArray(SR.switchTime);     //Works!
    b = StructureToByteArray(SR.switchParams[0]);       //Works!
    try
    {
        b = StructureToByteArray(SR.switchParams);      //Failed!
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

At run time the program failed to marshal the `SwitchParams` array nested in the `SwitchRecord` class.

The following error raise at `int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);` in `StructureToByteArray` function:

```
Type 'WpfApplication2.MainWindow+SwitchParam[]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
```

Comment: Why are you doing marshalling by hand instead of relying on the runtime to do it for native method call?

Comment: I'm quite new to C# - can you develop your suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

The `StrucyLayoutAttribute` says it in its name, it's supposed to be applied to structs, not classes, so you should have:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SwitchTime
{
    public byte st1 { get; set; }
    public byte st2 { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Size=3)]
struct SwitchParam
{
    public byte sp1 { get; set; }
    public byte sp2 { get; set; }
    public byte sp3 { get; set; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SwitchRecord
{
    public SwitchTime switchTime;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public SwitchParam[] switchParams;
}
```

And as a side-note, **please** in the future `PascalCase` your methods, don't `camelCase` them. Methods in C# are always `PascalCased` when following the conventions.

Comment: Note that some sites `camelCase` private methods.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Inconsistency much? I keep my point that it's a good habit to `PascalCase` any method, just for consistency.